# create-react-app shows an error of "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I use express for my API. I have a folder named app and another folder named server. app is the client app, using create-react-app as boilerplate, while server is express.js app for the API.

in the app.js file of the server, I wrote

```
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/build/index.html'));
})
```

But then when I call any API endpoint, I get

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

in the response. I'm confused; what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like your browser has disabled javascript. IS that right ?

Comment: @Panther nope..

Comment: make sure you define all your routes first then the catch-all case at the end

Comment: @AmrAly I did, here's my file https://pastebin.com/PRhLaH0E

Comment: No you did not you have defined all your routes after the catch all case just make sure to put the the above code after the routes handlers

Comment: This seems a browser issue. Enable the JavaScript from browser settings.

Comment: Did you have a look at this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286927/i-am-getting-error-in-console-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app-r

Comment: Are you running ```npm start``` to run your react app?

Answer (score 1):

In the build directory you have more files that just index.html. You also have build/js/main.buildNumber.js and build/css/main.buildNumber.css.
So when your frontend makes a request to https://yourdomain.com/css/main.buildNumber.js, it incorrectly returns index.html **not** main.js.

Instead, you should serve the contents of the build folder statically with express.static

```js
    app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
```

Or you can look into the "serve" node module to host your app. This will work nicely with react-router. `npm i -g serve` then `cd build` then `serve . --single -p 5000`. This will serve your app on port 5000 (http://localhost:5000).

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I was mixing styles for functional and class based components. Double check that you don't have any dangling `this` keywords, or perhaps some missing of the same.