# I am getting error in console "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to reactjs, I am working on a app. It was running fine, but when I've run npm run build command, I am getting error "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.". I have made changes in server.js file even I've given  "homepage": "./", but it did not solved my issue.

And I've checked by running laravel project, javascript is enabled in browser, also tried different browsers.

Someone please help me to overcome this error.

Comment: If you have built the app, it means the build process probably stripped out the dev-server. So you need a way to run the app i.e. a server.

Comment: It was running perfectly, but when I've run that npm run build command then i started getting issue.

Comment: Yes, the build process strips out the server. So you have no way of accessing the build because its only html, css & js. Can you add a js script to the main html file (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) & just add 'console.log("hello") with that js script file. See what happens. Please make sure the path to this new js file is correct.

Comment: @kayote I am not clear about what are you trying to say. please tell me which file I have to add and use that console.log('hello'). If i am doing this with simple <script> console.log('hello')</script>, it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. So you added a simple script with console.log & it worked. That means that Js files are being loaded in the browser & the issue may well be the delivery. Basically, you need to somehow serve your `built` react app. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/i-built-this-now-what-how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-a-digitalocean-droplet-662de0fe3f48

Comment: hello @Kayote I've added console.log by following your second last comment and it is working. I've followed the instructions to built, but none of the solution is working for me.

Comment: If I am installing new app by using create-react-app command, it is giving me same error, even I've not run build command on it yet.

Comment: I forgot to mention that, whole page is loading with content and images, but only sending or receiving data in nodejs is not working, may this information give something relevant.

Comment: Here's an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4438). It could be helpful.

Answer (score 27):

I received this message when no proxy to the server was specified inside client package.json file.

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

(where 5000 should be changed to whatever port number the server was setup to listen to. In my case it also required server restart once added)

Comment: this was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @MaxWidth how I know about port becuase there are so many ports display when I use this command : netstat -nltup

Comment: I solved my problem! But I still wonder why this happens when I use `npm run start`, since if I use `npm run build` then serve the build folder did not show this issue.

Comment: hi @Dylan i am facing opposite issue. it is working fine for `npm run start` but not for `serve -s build`. My backend is running on port 5151 and i have mentioned `"proxy": "http://localhost:5151"` in my package.json but it is working fine only in developer mode not in build mode.. any clues?

Comment: Restarting the server helped me!

Comment: @last_fix have you found the solution?

Comment: remember, changes to package.json needs the npm to be terminated and restarted

Answer (score 19):

I had same problem. My workable solution:

package.json:

```js
"homepage": "."
```

index.js:

```js
app.use(express.static(__dirname)); //here is important thing - no static directory, because all static :)

app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});
```

Comment: I'm a super noob, I get the obvios message `'app' is not defined      no-undef`, how should I init app? My index.js is super simple just declaring `ReactDOM.render(...)` with no `app` initialization.

Comment: The "homepage": "." was a life save, thanks!

Comment: Yep. Just needed to add "homepage": "." to the package.json, because my app is in a relative path and  react assumes that it's in the server root path

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure that this route must be appeared after at all other routes

```
app.get("/*", function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build', 'index.html'));
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I received this error because an API call that I was making was being blocked because of an invalid API key.

Answer (score 3):

Try to run in other browser and see if it is working.

If it works there then please try below things and refresh your website.

1. Right click and select Inspect.
2. Go to Application Tab.
3. Clear everything from **local storage, session storage and cookies**.
4. Refresh your website.

This resolved similar issue in my case and hope it will work for others.

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing the error "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." in reactjs then 9/10 times there is an issue with your API call. Please cross check API url string, parameters, action type, endpoints, action names, controller names and API call status. You'll be able to find the issue.
verify endpoint url again and again. You'll definitely find a solutions. Also check ur VPN access if you're able to hit the end point.

Go to console --> network tab and see ur API status

Answer (score 2):

after adding proxy in react package.json restart the reacr server. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, the class name wasn't following the patterns (must starts with uppercase). As soon as I corrected it everything started to work well.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your SignIn component or Register component, change the form tag  to a div tag  OR prevent the form default i.e (e.preventDefault).  Also make sure that **Javascript** is enabled in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I had been struggling with this issue the whole morning and after trying all the different hacks of setting up proxy and homepage, it still did not resolve.

And then I checked my js files, and because there was an error which was not being caught while npm start, it was not enabling javascript internally.

How I got to know that this did resolve the issue: Stopping the current run and correcting the issue that was there and then rerunning the server.

Comment: I had a similar issue - no error from the 'npm start' command but when I looked at the browser inspect console I saw an error. When it was resolved the app the started and displayed as expected.

Comment: Same. **npm start** succeeded with no errors, but I found a JS error in the browser's error console. Fixing that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had some cookies set in the same url (localhost:8080), probably from a previous development, and it was somehow messing with my React project. 
I only found out because (out of despair) I tried with another browser and it worked. 
I deleted the cookies and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Also a react newbie, I hit this issue. Remembering to add `ReactDOM.render(<MyClassName />, document.getElementById("root"));` fixed it for me.

Comment: IT might help to edit your answer to say *where* that might be added

Comment: Where was the code added setupProxy.JS file? I know this might be a long show, but I am experiencing similar problems as the original poster did.

Answer (score 0):

In your react project folder install serve if you haven't installed it before;

```
npm install -g serve
```

Then serve your project with a static server;

```
serve -s build
```

*The build is a folder generated by 'npm run build'.*

That's it! Visit

> http://localhost:5000

by default.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, when I was trying serve react static files in node js server. Was missing the following in index.js of server side code.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem right now. I forgot to bring ${REACT_APP_API}

before error

```
const res = await axios.get(`/api/products`)
console.log(res.data)
```

final solution

```
const res = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/api/products`)
console.log(res.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent the entire day troubleshooting this error for a React application on AWS using an ALB that forwards traffic from HTTPS to HTTP to a Docker container on ECS. The mistake I made was on the path-based forwarding rule to the target.

```
# Mistake
if path = “/“ then forward to target
# Corect
if path = “/*” then forward to target
```

The issue is that scripts referenced in index.html (from npm run build) did not resolve on a full DNS (such as https://example.com/static/js/main.js) and resulted in a 503 error in browser console for some reason. I saw tons of answers on other posts on the subject, but this was not one of the answers, so had to take the time to post about it. Because it wasn’t the React application at all - it was the application load balancer, so if any of this sounds familiar, take another look at your ALB… it might save you 8 hours if you just include that little star!!!

Comment: I am having a similar issue when I try to invoke an API gateway from an ALB DNS. The Lambda associated with this API triggers a batch job and I am calling it (I mean calling the API endpoint) from a react app from ALB DNS. Pls refer my post on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77681813/err-name-not-resolved-error-when-invoking-api-endpoint-from-react. which shows the code for react. My react app when accessed from ALB DNS says "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app" - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue was caused by a simple Javascript error, BUT because **npm start** built and ran with no errors or warnings, *I didn't know there was an error*. So I was stuck for hours.

I finally found the Javascript error **in the browser's console**, so check there.

(You can view the javascript console in your browser of choice, usually by right clicking on the page and choose **Inspect**).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in react I would say as a noob but you can cross-check the elements even in a proper code and you will see this error. Therefore do not search for a fix for the error rather fix your code for other possible issues like API related.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

It is case sensitive. Needs to start with upper case:

```js
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <**I**ndex />,
      errorElement: < ErrorPage />,
    },{
        path: "/login",
        element: < **L**ogin />,
    },{
        path: "/register",
        element: < **R**egister />,
    }
]);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).