# Can't run mlflow standalone react server

Tags: reactjs, mlflow

I need to run the frontend UI on a separate server as a stand-alone react app (not with all of the mlflow python server and packages). But when I run the production build, I get the following error:

> You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.

Reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow.git
cd mlflow/mlflow/server/js
```

In development mode, "npm start" it works just fine:

```
npm install
npm start
```

But when I've run it in production, I am getting the above error.

```
npm install
npm install -g serve
npm run build
serve -s build
```

I tried many things searching in forums, including this one:
[I am getting error in console "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286927/i-am-getting-error-in-console-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app-r).
but I didn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Is that "error" message shown in the browser? Sure about not having NoScript or similar running blocking the JavaScript execution?