# Axios requests returning HTML instead of JSON in production build. (React, Node.js, Heroku)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, axios

When I was sending the requests from the React frontend, I tested to see what type of response Axios gave on the Networks Tab for Chrome, Firefox, Postman and it showed that on localhost it's showing that it's application/json type while in production on Heroku it's text/html type. The routes that I set up are returning res.json() so I'm not sure what could be causing the problem.

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const path = require('path');

// Load env
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

// Routes
app.use('/', require('./routes/routes'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
{
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build'))); 

    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at port ${port}`);
});
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const db = mysql.createPool
({
    user: `${process.env.USER}`,
    host: `${process.env.HOST}`,
    password: `${process.env.PASSWORD}`,
    database: `${process.env.DATABASE}`,
    connectionLimit: 10,
    waitForConnections: true,
});

router.get('/user', (req, res) => 
{
    try 
    {
        let id = req.query.id;
        let admin = 0;

        // Check database to see if there's a user with the same ID as the one given to us.
        // If not, create a new user

        db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", [id], (err, result) => 
        {                    
            if(result.length == 0)
            {
                db.query("INSERT INTO users (id, admin) VALUES (?, ?)", [id, admin]);
            }

            return res.status(200).json({"result": result});
        });
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({error: "An error occurred with user"});
    }
});

router.post('/addMatch', (req, res) =>
{
    try 
    {
        let uid = req.body.uid;
        let mid = req.body.mid;
           
        db.query("INSERT INTO matches (uid, mid) VALUES (?, ?)", [uid, mid], (err, result) => 
        {
            return res.status(200).json({"result": result});              
        });
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {        
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({error: "An error occurred with addMatch"});
    }
});

router.post('/deleteMatch', (req, res) =>
{
    try 
    {
        let uid = req.body.uid;
        let mid = req.body.mid;
           
        db.query("DELETE FROM matches WHERE uid = ? AND mid = ?", [uid, mid], (err, result) => 
        {
            return res.status(200).json(result);              
        });
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {        
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({error: "An error occurred with deleteMatch"});
    }
});

router.get('/getMatches', (req, res) =>
{
    try 
    {
        let id = req.query.id;

        db.query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE id IN (SELECT mid FROM matches WHERE uid = ?);", [id], (err, matches) => 
        {
            return res.status(200).json(matches);
        });
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({error: "An error occurred with getMatches"});       
    }
});

router.get('/getMovie', (req, res) =>
{
    try 
    {
        let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;

        db.query(`SELECT * FROM media WHERE id = ${id}`, (err, result) => 
        {
            return res.status(200).json(result[0]);
        });
    } 
    catch (err) 
    {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({error: "An error occurred with getMovie"});
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Swipe.js**

```
import React from "react";
import MatchResults from "../components/MatchResults";
import Data from '../components/Data';
import { Container, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { withAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import axios from 'axios';

import '../styles/Swipe.css';

class Swipe extends React.Component 
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        const { user } = this.props.auth0;

        this.state = { 
            data: {},
            uid: user.sub.split('|')[1],
            matches: []
        };

        this.yesButtonApi = this.yesButtonApi.bind(this);
        this.noButtonApi = this.noButtonApi.bind(this);
        this.getMovie = this.getMovie.bind(this);
        this.getMatches = this.getMatches.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() 
    {
        this.getMovie();
        this.getMatches();
    }

    yesButtonApi() 
    {    
        try 
        {
            var body = {
                uid: this.state.uid,
                mid: this.state.data.id
            }  
    
            axios.post('/addMatch', body).then(() =>
            {
                this.getMovie();
                this.getMatches();
            });
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    noButtonApi() 
    {
        try 
        {
            this.getMovie();
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    getMovie()
    {
        try 
        {
            axios.get('/getMovie').then((response) =>
            {
                this.setState
                ({
                    data: response.data
                });
            });
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    getMatches()
    {
        try 
        {
            let uid = this.state.uid;

            axios.get(`/getMatches?id=${uid}`).then((response) => 
            {
                this.setState
                ({
                    matches: response.data
                });
            });
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    render() 
    {
        return (
            <div className="text-center">
                <Container className="swipe">
                    <Data title={this.state.data.title} description={this.state.data.description} rating={this.state.data.rating} preview={this.state.data.video}/>
                    <Button color="success" onClick={this.yesButtonApi} className="ml-sm">Yes</Button>
                    <Button color="danger" onClick={this.noButtonApi} className="ml-sm">No</Button>
                    <MatchResults matches={this.state.matches} uid={this.state.uid}/>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withAuth0(Swipe);
```

**MatchResults.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody, Container, CardHeader, Row, Col, Collapse, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import { AiFillStar } from 'react-icons/ai';
import '../styles/MatchResults.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class MatchResults extends Component 
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = { isOpen: false, matches: this.props.matches, uid: this.props.uid };

        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.getMatches = this.getMatches.bind(this);
        this.deleteButtonApi = this.deleteButtonApi.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps)
    {
        if(this.props !== prevProps)
        {
            this.setState
            ({
                matches: this.props.matches
            });
        }
    }

    toggle()
    {
        try 
        {
            this.setState
            ({
                isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
            });

            if(this.state.isOpen)
            {
                this.getMatches();
            }
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    getMatches()
    {
        try 
        {
            let uid = this.state.uid;

            axios.get(`/getMatches?id=${uid}`).then((response) => 
            {
                this.setState
                ({
                    matches: response.data
                });
            });
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    deleteButtonApi(e)
    {
        try 
        {
            var body = {
                uid: this.state.uid,
                mid: e.target.value
            }
    
            axios.post('/deleteMatch', body).then(() =>
            {
                this.getMatches();
            });
        } 
        catch (error) 
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    render() 
    {
        return (
            <Container className="match-results">
                <div className="text-center">
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle} style={{ marginBottom: '1rem' }}>View Matches</Button>
                    <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen}>
                        <Row>
                            {
                                this.state.matches.map((item, val) => 
                                {
                                    val += 1;
                                    return (
                                        <Col sm="12" md="6" lg="4">
                                            <Card key={val} className="match-results-card" data-testid="card">
                                                <CardHeader>
                                                    <div data-testid="title">
                                                        {item.title}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <span data-testid="rating">
                                                        <AiFillStar />
                                                        {item.rating}
                                                    </span>
                                                </CardHeader>
                                                <CardBody>
                                                    <div data-testid="description">
                                                        {item.description}
                                                    </div>
                                                </CardBody>
                                                <Button className="deleteBtn" color="danger" onClick={this.deleteButtonApi} value={item.id}>Delete</Button>
                                            </Card>
                                        </Col>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </Row>
                    </Collapse>
                </div>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default MatchResults;
```

**Localhost**

[image: Localhost]

**Localhost Response**

[image: Localhost Response]

**Production**

[image: Production]

**Production Response**

[image: Production Response]

Comment: What is the response that you're getting? Can you post a screenshot of Response tab for both Localhost and Production as well?

Comment: Check the content of the HTML. Usually it's a 404 error page served by your hosting provider or web server - meaning your request did not even reach your node.js code

Comment: @Mythos I added the response images I received for both localhost and production on the posts. They're from Postman but they're the same as Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response you're getting in your production deployment is the default index.html served when there's a problem with your node server configuration. It is not about the response being text/html, its about the node server being setup incorrectly (possibly none of the routes are working). The underlying problem could be anything, a few examples in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286927/i-am-getting-error-in-console-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app-r).

I suggest start by looking at your node.js logs in your production environment ([debugging Node.js application on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/debug-node-applications))

Comment: You were right. Apparently it needed a Procfile and adding "web: node index.js" to it to make sure that the node.js code was running. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Many things can cause the back end to return HTML instead of JSON.

One of the simple causes worth mentioning:

If a variable in the front end is undefined (e.g. an environment variable is undefined) and that variable is used in constructing urls the front end requests from the back end, which therefore don't exist e.g.

**[www.google.com/undefinedsearchTerms=panda](http://www.google.com/undefinedsearchTerms=panda)**

you may get HTML instead of JSON.

whereas perhaps in this hypothetical the front end should actually be requesting

**api.google.com/search/searchTerms=panda**