# AWS amplify deployment fails - You need to enable JavaScript to run this app

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I have a react app that I'm trying to deploy automtically using AWS amplify. I connected the repo and the build and deployment seems to be successfull:

[image]

But opening the url shows `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`  in the console

[image]

Building and serving the app locally using

```
$ npm run build
$ serve -s build
```

works fine.

I saw in the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286927/i-am-getting-error-in-console-you-need-to-enable-javascript-to-run-this-app-r) that this might be about setting the "proxy" in the package.json, but I'm not sure which port does AWS amplify uses and adding the line of the answer there (using `localhost:5000`) doesn't work either.

any ideas?

EDIT:

`amplify.yml`:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: Can you add your build .yml to your question?

Comment: where do I find that?